# Selector not firing if keyboard is visible

Tags: ios, swift, selector, swift5

I currently have a `UIView` with a `TableView` and a `TextField`. In my table view I create `EndTimeCell` (below), which have a selector set to trigger on the `UISwitch` value change. However, if the keyboard is visible, when I tap on the `UISwitch`, it changes, but the selector does not fire. Does anyone have any idea why?

I've attempted to modify the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to allow the touch to pass through but since I create the cells in the table view delegate, I have no way of checking if the tap is on the view element.

I've also tried resigning the keyboard, but it does nothing.

To be clear, the selector triggers fine if the keyboard is not showing, but does not fire if it is.

Thanks!

```swift
class EndTimeCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var label: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.text = "End"
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .semibold)
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.gray
        return lbl
    }()
    var enable: UISwitch = {
        let en = UISwitch()
        en.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSwitchValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return en
    }()
    
    
    var callback: (_ state: Bool) -> Void = {state in}
    
    
    @objc func onSwitchValueChanged(_ toggle: UISwitch) {
        print("CHANGED CHANGED CHANGED")
        if toggle.isOn {
            label.textColor = UIColor(named: "Secondary")
        } else {
            label.textColor = UIColor.gray
        }
        callback(toggle.isOn)
    }
    
    
    func layoutView() {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        enable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor),
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: Constants.padding + Constants.textFieldCornerRadius),
            
            enable.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor),
            enable.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -Constants.padding),
            
        ])
    }
    
    func setCallback(callback: @escaping (_ state: Bool) -> Void) {
        self.callback = callback
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(enable)
        layoutView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(enable)
        layoutView()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layoutView()
    }
}
```